# Why do I see TypeError when Pytorch's mul() function is used in combination with numpy?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am getting the following error in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_Q_learner.py", line 289, in <module>
    agent.replay_experience()
  File "deep_Q_learner.py", line 170, in replay_experience
    self.learn_from_batch_experience(experience_batch)
  File "deep_Q_learner.py", line 151, in learn_from_batch_experience
    self.Q_target(next_obs_batch).max(1)[0].data
TypeError: mul(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray
```

The link to the code is:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Intelligent-Agents-with-OpenAI-Gym/blob/master/ch6/deep_Q_learner.py

The error is seen only when self.DQN=SLP (see line#76)

Is there a fix to this issue? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you are supposed to pass in a torch.tensor object, where you are passing a numpy array object. Convert your numpy array to torch.tenosr by:

```
new_torch_tensor = torch.tensor(numpy_array)
```